Why does only 97% Oxygen transport occur as oxyhemoglobin?
I learnt that 97% oxygen is transported as oxyhemoglobin where as 3% is transported in the dissolved state through plasma. Moreover I've also seen that in the Oxygen Haemoglobin dissociation curve, saturation occurs at 97% instead of 100%, I can't relate why this happens.
Also what would happen if 100% saturation occurs?

so you are asking why a biological system is not perfect?

97% is transported as oxyhemoglobin and only 3% in dissolved state because oxygen has low solubility in plasma which cannot meet the body requirements so haemoglobin is the pigment which helps to make the transport easier.
If we see oxygen haemoglobin dissociation curve it gives us idea that what is the percentage saturation of the haemoglobin at particular partial pressure of oxygen. The near-complete saturation would be essential for an efficient oxygen transport to tissues and organs. 100% saturation of haemoglobin will occur only when the partial pressure of oxygen is very high which is not possible under normal conditions.
